# "Building blocks" for computable functions

Tags: computability, irrational-numbers, recursive-algorithms

In an (otherwise very enlightening) [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/848117/1792) to another [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/848040/functions-with-and-without-distinction-of-cases) of mine the question came up

> What functions are allowed as building blocks for [computable
>   functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computable_function)?

I was astonished that there is a matter of discussion: for me a [computable function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computable_function) $f: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ has been just **any** [$\mu$-recursive function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%9C-recursive_function). And there has not been a discussion about fancy "allowed building blocks" like $x\rightarrow \sqrt x$.

> How do I have to deal with this objection?

If I want to remain in the realm of natural numbers, (why) do I have to consider "building blocks" like $x\rightarrow \sqrt x$, which may yield intermediate results not finitely expressible by natural numbers (without introducing new symbols)?

Comment: Why does $x\mapsto\sqrt x$, in the context of the natural number not $\mu$-recursive? $$F(x)=\mu_y(y\cdot y=x)$$

Comment: Because it is not a total function? Do I have to consider *arbitrary* - not necessarily total = partial - functions?

Comment: In developing the theory, it is (was?) traditional to make the collection of "basic" functions very tiny, and let the tools (primitive recursion, minimalization) take care of the rest. Of course all functions are from $\mathbb{N}^k$ to $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: I don't understand your question, then. If you want to stay in the context of the natural numbers, what does $\sqrt2$ mean?

Comment: It was not *me* who introduced $\sqrt{x}$. That's what my question is about.

Comment: The general theory of computable functions is intimately tied to partial functions. But when you say $\sqrt{x}$ do you mean the partial function $\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$, or some other, total function? Is there something special about $\sqrt{x}$ that makes the partial computable function $f(x,y) = x-y$ a worse example for your purposes? Those answers may help me answer the original question.

Comment: I just was irritated by user Sten's remark with respect to my original question: *"The answer to this question heavily depends on what functions are allowed as building blocks [...] If we assume that $x\rightarrow x^2$ and $x\rightarrow \sqrt{x}$ are allowed [...]"* When the partial function $x\rightarrow \sqrt{x}$ is perfectly OK I do not understand what Sten means with "depends heavily".